# Javascript regex validation using input field attributes without eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am making a function to validate form input data (for practice) and maybe i'll also use it.

I was wondering if there is some way to apply the same functionality without eval as i have heard that it is bad on the js interpreter. Also improvements, if any. And also i would like to know if there is something that does the same job, ie, to apply reusable regex rules to input fields.

Here is my JavaScript validation function.

```
function validate(){
var num=/[0-9]+/g;
var alphanum=/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/g;
var alphanumSpace=/[0-9a-zA-Z\w_]+/g;
var alpha=/[a-zA-Z]+/g;
var alphaSpace=/[a-zA-Z\w]+/g;
var alphanumDot=/[0-9a-zA-Z\._]+/g;
var money=/[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2}?/g;


var flag=true;
var alertBox="Incorrect entries:\n\n";

$.each($('input[data-check]'),function(index,value){
  if(!eval(value.dataset.check+'.test("'+value.value+'")')){
    alertBox+=value.name+",\n";
    flag=false;
  }
});

alert(alertBox);
return flag;

}
```

Which is used to call on a form as

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
```

On fields that have the data-check attribute as any of the matching variables that i have defined as

```
<input data-check='num'>
```

This will call the test the regex against the num regex as defined in my code.

Comment: Also, your `alphanumSpace` can be simplified to just `[\w\s]+` which matches `[a-z0-9\s_]+`, `\w` stands for any word character - this set includes `alphanum` and `_` already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using `new RegExp` and `window[]`:

```
$.each($('input[data-check]'),function(index,value){
  var str = value.value;
  var patt = new RegExp(window[value.dataset.check]);
  var res = patt.test(str);
  if(!res){
    alertBox+=value.name+",\n";
    flag=false;
  }
});
```